# Delete a dimension in a NetCDF file

Tags: edit, dimension, netcdf, nco

I have a netCDF file with 8 variables and 4 dimensions: latitude (dim: 26), longitude (dim:17), time (dim: a lot) and level (dim:1, pressure level). In order to use it in a specific program I need to have only 3 dimensions: latitude, longitude and time.

Is there an easy way to delete the level dimension in each variable?

I've found `ncwa -a old_dim ifile.nc ofile.nc` but sometimes it converts the type from short to float. When it keeps the short type the attributes "scale factor" and "add.offset" are deleted. The problem is that I want to keep the short type with scale factor and add offset.

Answer (score 5):

Your method is correct, however, your input data are "packed". Repack the output file with **ncpdq** after averaging-out the level dimension with **ncwa**:

```
ncpdq ofile.nc ofile2.nc
```

and you are done. See docs [here](http://nco.sf.net/nco.html#ncpdq).